# Backup database with multiple tables powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

My objective is to backup a database to a spreadsheet. The database uses multiple tables. I'd like to save each table into it's own sheet in the spreadsheet. That way everything is in a single file. I also want to avoid using excel.

```
$server = "***\***"
$database = "***"
$username = "***"
$password = '***'
$tablequery = "SELECT schemas.name as schemaName, tables.name as tableName from sys.tables inner join sys.schemas ON tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id"
#Delcare Connection Variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3}"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database, $username, $password)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection

#Load up the Tables in a dataset
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()

Import-Module ImportExcel

foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows) {
    $queryData = "SELECT * FROM [$($Row[0])].[$($Row[1])]"

    $command.CommandText = $queryData
    $command.Connection = $connection
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()
    $Columns = $DataSet.Tables[0].Columns.ColumnName
    $DataSet.Tables[0] | Select-Object -Property $Columns | Export-Excel -workSheetName $Row[1] -path C:\Users\bsben\Desktop\Demo.xlsx
}
```

Here's my current code. It does what I need. The problem is it has to write to the file for every table. The end result is for my current database it writes to the file 94 times. It ends up taking about 10 seconds.
The way I see it working is adapting what's going to be saved into an object.

Comment: You may try `ForEach-Object   -Parallel` to run queries in parallel https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0):

This Idea is not an optimal solution and not recommended. Imagine if you have 1000+ tables in your DB and imaging you have 50+ DB inside your DB instance; then 1000+ sheets would be required in one excel file. Do you really think that it is possible to read after that in that level ?

Although there is a direct way to export the tables of DB to EXCEL. Please refer the link below :

[Export-sql-server-tables-to-Excel/](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6396/export-sql-server-tables-to-excel/)

Storing everything in one single Flat file is going to make life more complicated when you cannot do anything with the file in future.
Take backups based on the backup tools or script the mdf,ldf,ndf in proper paths.

As per the comment, here is the link for [sql-database-backups-using-powershell-module-dbatools](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-database-backups-using-powershell-module-dbatools/)

Comment: I realize it's not optimal. That's why I've been looking for something better. I've been hoping for an option that doesn't require an install. It's why I've targeted using scripting.

Comment: Directly use the SQL commands to take the MDF/NDF/LDF backups to directory and have it do a File validation after that. That should be your solution . @Kaws 
There is a direct command to use [BACKUP-SQLDATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/backup-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps)

Comment: That looks promising, I'd like an option to target the option format.

Comment: @Kaws: You can use the Powershell module of DBATools for that . I have given the link in the answer itself